# how to convert java webapplication into single exe file?

Tags: binding, struts2, exe, code-access-security

I want to convert my struts2 web application into an `exe` format so that `exe` file will load my project into server and database into MySQL.

Are there any such tools available for loading files into a folder?

Are there any forms other than `.exe` to which I could convert my project to do this action?

Is it possible to decrypt the code from class file to java file?

Which is the most secure form for a struts2 project for loading into a server?

Answer (score 1):

You want to convert it to executable one?? generally installer came to assist auto installation like if you have created a product using all these technology and you want save your customer from all the setting and installation processes like database configuration,other configurations etc.

```
Is it possible to decrypt the code from class format to java format
```

there are many java d-compilers available which help you to convert .class files to java files though they sometime fails to convert it 100% but in most cases they tend to show some one what they actually want  to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can't load an `exe` file into a web server.

I suppose you could create an executable that includes a server and your war file, but I would strongly discourage the practice.

You *could* obfuscate (e.g., with [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)) and/or encrypt your .class files, but if they're determined to get to your unobfuscated byte code, they almost certainly will.

If they're not that determined, then it's probably not important enough to go through all the effort, debugging, and so on.

Comment: we created ERP Web pplication ,so we want to bundle all softwares required for application with webapplication as a single windows installer. how can i do .Thanks in advance